# Lotus Notes API giving error in Document Collection merge

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I have been working for accessing the Lotus Notes(.nsf) data from the external server using JAVA Lotus notes API, but I'm getting the following error for DocumentCollection:

```
"NotesException: Not implemented\r\n\tat lotus.domino.cso.Base.notImplemented(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat lotus.domino.cso.DocumentCollection.merge(Unknown Source)
```

The Code i am using is :

```
Document docParent = docColParents.getFirstDocument();
while(docParent != null){
        docColResponses.merge(docParent.getResponses());
        docTemp = docColParents.getNextDocument();
        docParent.recycle();
        docParent = docTemp;
}
```

Comment: Precisely as Knut said in his answer, your import looks to be attempting to pull `lotus.domino.cso.DocumentCollection` when you should be importing `lotus.domino.DocumentCollection`. The `lotus.domino` package is where you want to import from.

Answer (score 3):

Use/import class

```
lotus.domino.DocumentCollection
```

(not lotus.domino.**cso**.DocumentCollection).

*Update*

Initialize docColResponses with null and *assign* responses for first document to it and *merge* responses for the next documents:

```
import lotus.domino.DocumentCollection;
...
    DocumentCollection docColResponses = null;
    ...
    while (docParent != null) {
        if (docColResponses == null) {
            docColResponses = docParent.getResponses();
        } else {
            docColResponses.merge(docParent.getResponses());
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I checked the imports:
Import lotus.domino.Database;
Import lotus.domino.Document;
Import lotus.domino.DocumentCollection;
Import lotus.domino.NotesException;
Import lotus.domino.Session;
Import lotus.domino.View;
Import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
Import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;
Import lotus.domino.ViewNavigator;

Comment: Please confirm: are you using NCSO.jar instead of Notes.jar? Where is your code running? Where did you get your NCSO.jar file from? What version is it?

Comment: I added some code I tested before. It avoids issues with initializing a DocumentCollection you might get with other approaches.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I'm using "C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Domino\data\domino\java\NCSO.jar". My code is running as a 'restservlet' in DAS. The Notes version is 8.5.3.

Comment: It seems you are running the code on the Domino server. Can't you use Notes.jar instead of NCSO.jar? Does that not work in your configuration?